# How to reformulate linear constraint into a geometric programming constraint?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, linear-programming, constraints, geometric-programming

Arcording to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017667/what-is-the-correct-change-of-variables-to-yield-convexity-in-this-nonlinear-opt), smart manipulation of difficult non-linear constraints by a change of variable can lead to a formulation of  [Geometric Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_programming).

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min }&{\underbrace {{f_0}\left( x \right)}_{{\rm{Posynomial}}}}\\
{s.t}&{\underbrace {{f_i}\left( x \right)}_{{\rm{Posynomial}}} \le 1}\\
{}&{\underbrace {{g_i}\left( x \right)}_{{\rm{Monomial}}} = 1}
\end{array}$

In my case, I was having trouble of reformulating the following simple linear constraints into GP constrainst:

$x + y \ge 1$

Does that mean that this simple linear constraint cannot be reformulate as a GP constraints ${\underbrace {{f_i}\left( x \right)}_{{\rm{Posynomial}}} \le 1}$ ?

As a follow up question, I am having a strange gut feeling that although GP has a great expressive power, it cannot be used to express all Linear Programming problem but I am not sure if I am correct on this issue or not?

**Edit**:
In my application I am pretty sure that all of my decision variable x and y are in the interval of [0,1] that is $x,y \in \left[ {0,1} \right]$ . I am not sure if this could help !

Please help me with this,

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: It does not seem possible. Geometric programming is just a change of variables where $u=\log(x), v=\log(y)$. So then $x+y\geq 1$ transforms to the nonconvex constraint $e^u+ e^v \geq 1$.

Comment: Arbitrary linear programs are not GP. These are different classes.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Please don't use "EDIT:" - we have revision history, so no need to mark what has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example $x+y \ge 1$ with $x,y\in[0,1]$, you can introduce $\bar{x}$ to represent $1-x$ and $\bar{y}$ to represent $1-y$.  Then your constraint becomes $1-\bar{x}+1-\bar{y} \ge 1$, equivalently, the posynomial constraint $\bar{x}+\bar{y} \le 1$.